# How to display a children form as wpf into MDI Container is normal mdi form

Tags: c#, wpf

How to display WPF form in normal created MDI windows form.

We create form as MDI.
add menu bar click menu it will display wpf form in main container MDi form.

[image]

```
 private void newStudentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      StudentRegister student=  new StudentRegister();
     student.ShowDialog(); 
    }
```

Problem is click on task bar child form go outside.

Answer (score 2):

As my understanding you want to open child page inside MDI page. first of in WPF don't have MDI window.

if you are using " student.ShowDialog(); " then page or window will open as a popup.

possible solution:--

you can use ContentControl on main window and create usercontrol instead of window. then you can add user control to ContentControl.

```
<Border ClipToBounds="True" Grid.Row="1" Background="WhiteSmoke">
  <ContentControl x:Name="DetailsControl" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Border>

var student= new StudentRegister ();
DetailsControl.Content = student;
```

below link may help.

http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=AvalonDock

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22927/Multiple-Window-Interface-for-WPF